# Как получить данные из localStorage в store Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Подскажите, как получить данные из `localStorage` в store Nuxt js

```
import getters from './getters'
import actions from './actions'
import mutations from './mutations'

const cart = window.localStorage.getItem('cart')
const totalCart = window.localStorage.getItem('totalCart')
const costCart = window.localStorage.getItem('costCart')

export default {
  state: {
    cart: cart ? JSON.parse(cart) : [],
    totalCart: totalCart ? parseInt(totalCart) : 0,
    costCart: costCart ? parseInt(costCart) : 0,
    geo: [],
    error: []
  },
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

так пишет `window is not defined`

Comment: Вым нужно определиться где работает скрипт. На клиенте или на Сервере

Comment: Если на сервере то что такое localStorage

Comment: да, я вдуплил что на сервере нет этого, как тогда можно реализовать подгрузку?

Comment: отправляйте через куки либо любым другим способом на сервер данные

Comment: @Aslero Смотрите в сторону `nuxtServerInit` в index модуле Vuex, генерируйте и подгружайте нужные при инициализации скрипта. Токен можно брать из кук.

Comment: это как? создать мутацию INIT_CART_FROM_LOCALSTORAGE и в nuxtServerInit commit?

Answer (score 0):

не знаю насколько верно все сделал, но работает, поправьте плз, если это все ккал)))

сделал плагин

nuxt-client-init.js

```
export default async (context) => {
  await context.store.dispatch('nuxtClientInit', context)
}
```

в nuxt.config.js в plugins добавил

```
{ src: '~/plugins/app/nuxt-client-init.js', mode: 'client'},
```

в actions store добавил

```
nuxtClientInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    commit('INIT_CART_FROM_LOCALSTORAGE')
  },
```

сама мутация

```
INIT_CART_FROM_LOCALSTORAGE (state) {
    const cart = window.localStorage.getItem('cart')
    const totalCart = window.localStorage.getItem('totalCart')
    const costCart = window.localStorage.getItem('costCart')

    state.cart = cart ? JSON.parse(cart) : []
    state.totalCart = totalCart ? parseInt(totalCart) : 0
    state.costCart = costCart ? parseInt(costCart) : 0
  },
```